# filter by default with now() and earlier djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm passing date parameters from `angualrjs` controller to my restapi, now the date parameter is not specified so I need to filter by default with now() and earlier on parameter which I'm sending to `restapi` so if I'm understanding correctly filter should be in the get function on the view, probably, like I said probably because I'm in a dilemma on this one, and asking from someone to explain to me how can I do this. You can check my `controller` and view down bellow.

```
app = angular.module 'cms.sales'

app.controller 'FilterContactsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  ($scope, $http) ->
    savedSuccessMessage = "Contact leads list was updated"
    savedFailMessage = "Failed to update contact leads list"
    $scope.selectDate = null

    $scope.init = (nextSelectedDate)->
      if nextSelectedDate
        $scope.selectDate = nextSelectedDate
      else
        $scope.selectDate = ""


    $scope.doAction = () ->
      data = {
        select_date: $scope.selectDate
      }
      $http.post("/api/sales/lead_contact/", data).then(
        nextContactListUpdateSuccess, nextContactListUpdateFailed
      )

    nextContactListUpdateSuccess = ()->
      ClientNotifications.showNotification("Success", "Contact Leads list page was updated", "success")

    nextContactListUpdateFailed = () ->
      ClientNotifications.showNotification("Alert", "Failed to update contact leads list page", "alert")

]
```

ModelViewSet:

```
class LeadContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = LeadContact.objects.none()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.has_perm('vinclucms_sales.can_view_full_lead_contact_list'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.all()
        elif user.has_perm('cms_sales.can_view_lead_contact'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.filter(account_handler=user)
        return queryset

    # rest of the view below
    .....
```

Comment: you mean you want to filter the LeadContact with `now()` and `earlier` if `$scope.selectDate` is not specified? you can do that by creating another function called `def list(self, request)` and do your logic there.

Comment: oh, yes, thanks, was about to try that